# throw System.StackOverflowException while creating object

Tags: c#-4.0

when i run my code in console i find this massage: Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.

```
public class MyDictionary< TKey, Tvalue> : Dictionary<TKey,Tvalue>
{
private MyDictionary<TKey, Tvalue> md;
public MyDictionary(int size)
{md = new MyDictionary<TKey, Tvalue>(size);}}
static void Main(string[] args)
{var sOn = new MyDictionary<int, string>(4);}
```

when i use debug mode i find the problem in the constructor but i don't know
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyDictionary` class contains an instance of a `MyDictionary`. The constructor initializes this member, which in turn calls the constructor on that member, which has its own member, and so on until you exhaust the call stack and get the exception.

You probably don't need this member, but need to pass the `size` argument to the `base` constructor:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, Tvalue> : Dictionary<TKey, Tvalue>
{
    public MyDictionary(int size) : base(size) {}
    // Here ------------------------^

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var sOn = new MyDictionary<int, string>(4);
    }
}
```